# Use docker without registry for gitlab-ci

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

My school has a personal gitlab setup, but it doesn't have a registry setup for docker images.

What I want to do is run my pipeline with docker, so that I can build, test etc in a docker environment.

Right now i am trying random stuff because I don't know what I am doing. This is what I have now:

Gitlab-ci:

```
image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

before_script:
  - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY

build-master:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE"

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
```

[My secret variables on gitlab:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBYt4.jpg)

[My error message in the pipeline:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6vA9.jpg)

Something else I tried uses a gitlab repo. This uses the docker image for ros correctly, but in my application I also use opencv, so I want to add more to the docker image. If i know how to do that in the example below, thats also an option. On top of this, in the example below i can't run tests.

Gitlab-ci:

```
image: ros:kinetic-ros-core

stages:
- build

variables:
  ROS_PACKAGES_TO_INSTALL: ""
  USE_ROSDEP: "true"

cache:
  paths:
    - ccache/

before_script:
 - git clone https://gitlab.com/VictorLamoine/ros_gitlab_ci.git
 - source ros_gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci.bash


catkin_make:
  stage: build
  script:
    - catkin_make

catkin_build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - catkin build --summarize --no-status --force-color
```

As I said I have tried many things, this is just the latest thing I have tried. How can I run my runners and gitlab-ci with docker without a gitlab registry?

Comment: You say that you don't have a registry, but all the commands you have in your ci file are ones that interact with a registry. What exactly do you want the ci pipeline to do?

Comment: I read somewhere that you can use secret variables to link to dockerhub

Comment: `$CI_REGISTRY...` variables are built-in, and they always refer to the GitLab registry. Rename your variables to something else.

Comment: I don't want to push something to dockerhub. I want to use a docker image to build my application in the pipeline, instead of for example shell.

Comment: After changing the secret variables I get the same error message. Also note that I am trying to use this image: https://hub.docker.com/r/fjctp/armhf-ros-kinetic-opencv3/ . If I could make my own image, this would be even better.

Comment: You are trying to build an image in your CI (`docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE" .`) then push it. As a first step I'd suggest removing everything but the build. Remove all references to CI_REGISTRY. I think this is still going to fail, in which case you will know it's not about the registry ;).
I would also try adding a `docker info` command in `before_scripts` to see if that passes.

Comment: Still the following error: "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?". What should I put in the image name for the docker image, and how do I set it up on my pc so the runners can use it. Maybe that's where my issue is.

Answer (score 1):

Just use it withouth registry.
You just need to insert this to gitlab runner config file:

**pull_policy = "if-not-present"**

Thats enough, and remove commands like:

**docker push ...**
**docker pull ...**

Or even insert "|| true" at the end of the push pull command if you want to keep push pull in case, like this:

**docker pull ... || true;**

Which keeps your code to continue if command fail.
Just dont forget that : **pull_policy = "if-not-present"** , which allow You to run docker image withouth pull and push.
As image is in case if mussing builded, this works.

example:

```
[[runners]]
  name = "Runner name"
  url = ...
  ...
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    image = ...
    pull_policy = "if-not-present"
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change these secret variables to point to docker-hub registry server.

You have to create your account on that https://hub.docker.com/ and then use that details to configure - gitlab secret variables.

Comment: That's what I tried, but it gives the error that docker isn't running. I tried running it localy on my pc but it isn't working for some reason.

Could you also say what the values of the secret variables should be? Maybe I have them wrong